# How to best name the interval between two adjacent quantiles? Explained with the example of quartiles

Tags: terminology, quantiles

Officially, there are three quartiles: They are the boundaries that divide any distribution into four equally populated intervals.

Confusingly, people also refer to these 4 intervals as quartiles!

Now, my question is if there is a usable term to easily and shortly refer to these intervals, and so that everybody will understand?

Comment: You’re looking for a name for the fraction of data? You can call it by that fraction. The lowest quarter; the third quarter. The Wikipedia article TMat linked agrees with calling these quarters.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence with a blank where you would like to use this term?

Answer (score 0):

[interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range), [inderdecile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdecile_range) or more generally interquantile range can be used.

Comment: IQR is the difference between the third and first quartiles; IDR is between the ninth and first deciles. This is stated in the articles you linked. It’s not a name for the interval of data itself.

Comment: Note the OP is interested in the interval between two *adjacent* quantiles.

Comment: Yes, exactly @RichardHardy

Let's say I computed the three quartiles for my distribution, and do subsequent analyses on the four stratified intervals. What would be an easy, elegant, and correct way to label these 4 intervals?

Comment: In case there is no good word for these bins, I'm inclined to call the intervals "quartiles" and the official quartiles "quartile boundaries". Seems easy and elegant, but not sure if math folks would be happy about that.

Comment: @MichaelBeyeler, I think I understand your question but I do not have an answer for it.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy you are right, it is a mistake. I would tend to call that an "interquantile interval" by analogy with the interquantile range. One advantage is that as it contains the word "interval" we can't be mistaken and think that it is a real value (i.e. it is not the range :) ).